# How to take multiple values of a column in single column field in HP loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have one script in HP-LoadRunner, I want to take multiple values of column in a single field.

I have this:

> Variable1
>
> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test4

I am trying to do this:

> Variale1
>
> test1,test2,test3,test4

I tried with writing a 'C' code to solve this but unfortunately not able to find proper solution.

Is this possible with writing a code it will change into single column field during 1st test run and take the values from that single column field ?

Kindly Help me out, Either in terms of writing 'C' code in script or something to change in Excel/.dat file.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please clarify if you are trying to feed data into a field from a file representing user input or if you are trying to capture data from the screen/server to use later in the same business process

Comment: 1st time when i am running Loadrunner script, then i am taking parameter values from one file which i showed in given " I have this: "  ......and i am passing it in a request...... then again i want to write those fetched values into new file in the form of given " I am trying to do this "

Comment: "....then again i want to write those fetched values into new file ...."  See Virtual Table Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I faced the same problem so Try this:-

```
 long fp;
 int i,j;
 char *SearchValue;
 char ch[10];


Action()
{
   fp=fopen("External file path","w");      

   for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
   {
   fputs("\"",fp);
   fputs(lr_eval_string("{Internal file parameter}"),fp);               

   for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
    {
        fputs(",",fp);
        fputs(lr_eval_string("{Internal file parameter}"),fp);
     }

    fputs("\"",fp);

    fputs("\n",fp);                     
   }
   fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh, That finally solved my problem :)  Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

This solution will help you if your "Variable1" appears only once in your script.
In your script while replacing the parameter, instead of using "{Variable1}"
use "{Variable1},{Variable1},{Variable1},{Variable1}" and in your parameter settings provide "update value on: each occurrence".

Comment: Thanks @Karthik, Your answer was helpful little bit, I was applying loop as you given me an idea and finally saurabh dadhich posted full code with answer.